# Can I use a 5G antenna on my 4G router and get 5G speeds or do I need a 5G router

Tags: antenna, router, 5g, 4g

I have a Huawei B535 4G router at home. The SIM card sitting in it and the subscription also supports 5G. Will it be enough to just add an external antenna like this one: https://triax.com/shop/en/o5a-06w-omnidirectional-5g-antenna-109602 to get 5G speeds or would I need to have an actual dedicated 5G router like this one: https://consumer.huawei.com/en/routers/5g-cpe-pro-2/ ?

Comment: An antenna doesn't care about the *content* of the signals it's converting between free-space radiation and guided wave. All it cares about is frequency. So, no. Your antenna necessarily has to support the frequencies you want to use, but screwing a wifi antenna to your grandpa's car radio does not make it an access point, either.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the chipset in the router supports 5G, no antenna or SIM card can make it work with 5G.